# Find fit of an experimental PDF

Tags: fitting, data, probability-or-statistics, modeling

After quite some struggle, I managed to put up a code that is syntaxically correct. The goal is to find the parameters for a gamma distribution that best match experimental data. The data is a set of delays, tradionnally modeled as a gamma distribution according to the literature. My problem is that I (or LinearModelFit) don't find a correct fit. I wonder if it is because "t" is a list of {x,y}.
Here is the dataset:
https://transfer.sh/AqOzl/tt12-tt22-20070101-20070128.csv.fix.csv
and here is the code I use:

```
input = tt12-tt22-20070101-20070128.csv.fix.csv
d = SemanticImport[ input, Delimiters -> "," ]
selection = Normal@d[[All, "Delay"]]

ed = EmpiricalDistribution[ selection ]
DiscretePlot[PDF[ed,x],{x,selection}]

t= Table[{x, PDF[EmpiricalDistribution[selection], x]}, {x, selection}];
ListPlot[t] 


nlm = NonlinearModelFit[ t, PDF[GammaDistribution[shape,scale],x], {shape,scale}, x]

Show[ListPlot[t], Plot[nlm[x], {x, 0, 50} ] ]
```

I uploaded 2 pictures if you can't run the previous code.
[image: PDF of the experimental data]
[image: Incorrect Gamma fit found]

Looking forward for some help
Best regards

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Pure `GammaDistribution` does not seem at all like a good fit even visually. You need probably a `MixtureDistribution`. You could BTW skip `NonlinearModelFit` and start playing with `FindDistributionParameters`. But I think you are better of trying out latest WL function [FindDistribution](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindDistribution.html). In automated regime it finds almost what you need:

```
dis = FindDistribution[selection]
```

> MixtureDistribution[{0.71794, 
>         0.28206}, {CauchyDistribution[11.0632, 0.084502], 
>         GammaDistribution[8525.77, 0.00126454]}]

but it does not look good on the comparative plot below. So try various restrictions:

```
disGG = FindDistribution[selection, 
  TargetFunctions -> {BetaDistribution, NormalDistribution, 
    GammaDistribution}]
```

> MixtureDistribution[{0.0386662, 
>         0.961334}, {GammaDistribution[15.4335, 0.924904], 
>         NormalDistribution[10.9758, 0.195018]}]

...that was not the best one - but you're catching the drift. Here is how to see:

```
Show[
 Histogram[selection, {10, 12, .05}, "ProbabilityDensity",
  PlotTheme -> "Business"],
 Plot[{PDF[dis, x], PDF[disGG, x]}, {x, 10, 12}, PlotRange -> All,
  PlotTheme -> "Detailed", PlotStyle -> 1]]
```

[image]

Check out also section [Hypothesis Tests](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/HypothesisTests.html). Or you could go really sofisticat on that and require say 5 best distributions according to say a parameter `"PearsonChiSquare"`:

```
dis = FindDistribution[selection, 5, "PearsonChiSquare"];

Show[
 Histogram[selection, {10, 12, .05}, "ProbabilityDensity",
  PlotTheme -> "Business"],
 Plot[Evaluate[PDF[#, x] & /@ dis[[All, 1]]], {x, 10, 12}, 
  PlotRange -> All,
  PlotTheme -> "Detailed", PlotStyle -> 1]]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer that gives me a lot to think about. When trying to run "dis = FindDistribution[selection]" in Mathematica 10.0.2 (linux), it does not return a result like yours but outputs "FindDistribution[{11.126, 10.801, 10....". Any idea why please ?

Comment: @mattator do your docs F1 have article for this function? If not this maybe 10.1. If yes, can you run simple examples from there?

Comment: That was it indeed. Now it works. Thanks again !

Comment: @mattator Is your data set still available?  The link provided above does not work for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Because the distribution is clearly not a gamma distribution, finding estimates of gamma parameters won't be of much use.  If there is a theoretical or historical reason to believe that a mixture of two or more distributions should describe the results of the process generating the data, then the above approaches are fine.

But if you just need a description of the distribution, then a nonparametric density estimate using `SmoothKernelDistribution` will provide a much better fit than any of those shown above.  (Unfortunately I can't display it for your data as the link no longer works - at least it doesn't work for me.)  The code might look as follows:

```
(* Construct nonparametric density estimate *)
f = SmoothKernelDistribution[selection];

(* Plot nonparametric density estimate *)
Plot[PDF[f, x], {x, 10, 12, 0.01}]
```

The downside is that the distribution can't be described in just a few parameters.  But again, unless there's a good reason be believe that the distribution can be described with a few parameters from a specific distributional family, there's no reason to restrict yourself in that way.